# HTTP Parameter pollution attack

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, security

I developed a web application and deployed into the server and my security team come up with the below security remidiation issue.

**Reflected HTML Parameter Pollution (HPP) is an injection weakness vulnerability that occurs when an attacker can inject a delimiter and change the parameters of a URL generated by an application. The consequences of the attack depend upon the functionality of the application, but may include accessing and potentially exploiting uncontrollable variables, conducting other attacks such as Cross-Site Request Forgery, or altering application behavior in an unintended manner. Recommendations include using strict validation inputs to ensure that the encoded parameter delimiter “%26” is handled properly by the server, and using URL encoding whenever user-supplied content is contained within links or other forms of output generated by the application.**

Can any one have the idea about how to prevent HTML parameter pollution in asp.net

here is the script code in the webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        document.onclick = doNavigationCheck ;  
        var srNumberFinal="";

        function OpenDetailsWindow(srNumber)
        {    
            window.open("xxx.aspx?SRNumber="+srNumber+ "","","minimize=no,maximize=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,width=800,directories=no,resizable=yes,titlebar=no");
        }

        function OpenPrintWindow()
        {
            var querystrActivityId = "<%=Request.QueryString["activityId"]%>";

            if(querystrActivityId != "")
            {
                var url = "abc.aspx?id=" + "<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>" + "&activityId=" + querystrActivityId + "";
            }
            else
            {

                var hdrActivityId = document.getElementById('<%=uxHdnHdrActivityId.ClientID%>').value;
                var url = "PrintServiceRequestDetail.aspx?id=" + "<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>" + "&activityId=" + hdrActivityId + "";
            }

            childWinReference=window.open(url, "ChildWin","minimize=yes,maximize=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,location=no,directories=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no");
            childWinReference.focus();
        }

        function NavigateSRCopy(srNumber)
        {    
            srNumberFinal = srNumber;

            if (srNumber != "undefined" && srNumber != null && srNumber != "")
            {
                new Ajax.Request('<%= (Request.ApplicationPath != "/") ? Request.ApplicationPath : string.Empty %>/xxx/AutoCompleteService.asmx/CheckFormID'
                                        , { method: 'post', postBody: 'srNumber=' + srNumber, onComplete: SearchResponse });
            }
        }

        function SearchResponse(xmlResponse)
        {
            var xmlDoc;

            try //Internet Explorer
            {
                xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async="false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlResponse.responseText);
            }  
            catch(e)
            {
                try // Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
                {
                    parser=new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlResponse.responseText,"text/xml");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    alert(e.message);   
                    return;
                }
            }

            if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0] != null)
            {
                formID = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
            }
            else
            {
                formID = null;
            }

            if(formID != null && formID != "")
            {          
                window.location.href = '/CustomerSupportRequest/CreateServiceRequest.aspx?id=' + formID + '&TemplateSR=' + srNumberFinal + '&Frompage=CopySR';

                return true;
            }
            else
            {    
                alert("This Service Request cannot be copied because it meets at least one of these conditions: \t\t\n\n        * It was created prior to 10/15/2008 \n        * It was auto generated as part of the Report Requeue Process \n        * It was auto generated as part of the ERA Requeue Process \n        * It was not created online");
            }
        }

        function UpdateChildCases()
        {
            var modalPopup = $find('modalParentChildComments');
            modalPopup.show(); 
        }

        function HideParentChildPopup()
        {
            var modalPopup = $find('modalParentChildComments');
            modalPopup.hide(); 
            return false;
        }

        function HideErrorSRNumsPopup()
        {
            var modalPopup = $find('modalParentErrorSRNumDisplay');
            modalPopup.hide(); 
            return false;
        }

        function HideRetrySRNumsPopup()
        {
            var modalPopup = $find('modalRetrySRNumDisplay');
            modalPopup.hide(); 
            return false;
        }

        function RemoveParent_ChildFlag(type)
        {
            var childCases = document.getElementById("<%=uxHdnChildCases.ClientID %>");
            var msg = "";
            var btn;

            if(type == "Child")
            {
                if(childCases.value.indexOf(',') != -1)
                    msg = "Are you sure you want to remove the Child flag from this Service Request?";
                else   
                    msg = "This is the only child associated to the parent case.  Removing the child flag will also remove the parent flag from the associated case.  Choose OK to remove the flags, or Cancel to close this dialog";

                btn = document.getElementById('<%=uxRemoveChildFlag.ClientID%>');
            }   
            else
            {
                msg = "Removing the parent flag from this case will also remove the child flag from all associated cases.  Are you sure you want to remove the Parent flag from this Service Request?";
                btn = document.getElementById('<%=uxRemoveParentFlag.ClientID%>');
            }

            if(btn)
            {
                if(!confirm(msg))
                {
                    return false;   
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.click();
                }
            } 
        }

        function limitTextForParentChildComments() 
        {   
            var objLblCharCount = document.getElementById('uxLblPCCharCount');
            var objTxtComments = document.getElementById('<%=txtParentComment.ClientID%>');

            if (objTxtComments.value.length > 1500) 
            {
                objTxtComments.value = objTxtComments.value.substring(0, 1500);
            } 
            else 
            {
                objLblCharCount.innerHTML = 1500 - objTxtComments.value.length + " ";
            }

            setTimeout("limitTextForParentChildComments()",50);
        }

        function ValidateInputs()
        {
            var lblErrorMessage = document.getElementById('<%=lblCommentErrorTxt.ClientID%>');
            var objTxtComments = document.getElementById('<%=txtParentComment.ClientID%>');

            if(objTxtComments.value.trim() == "")
            {
                lblErrorMessage.style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Clean all the strings with a `<%= Request`

Comment: look at `Encode` and `Decode` and make necessary validations; for example, you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809142/http-parameter-pollution)

Comment: can you please give me a small example how to clean all string @mplungjan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-sanitize-input-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 1):

As per [OWASP Testing for HTTP Parameter pollution](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_(OTG-INPVAL-004)), ASP.NET is not vulnerable to HPP because ASP.NET will return all occurrences of a query string value concatenated with a comma (e.g. `color=red&color=blue` gives `color=red,blue`).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811699/413180) for an example explanation.

That said, your code appears to be vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) instead:

```
var querystrActivityId = "<%=Request.QueryString["activityId"]%>";
```

If the query string parameter `activityId="; alert('xss');"` (URL encoded of course), then an alert box will trigger on your application because this code will be generated in your script tag.

```
var querystrActivityId = ""; alert('xss');"";
```